# Using squeeze theorem to compute limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

From Saff and Snider's *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis*, section 4.3, problem 10.

Verify that if $f$ is continuous at $z$, then $\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int_{0}^{1}f(z+t\Delta z) dt = f(z)$.

Attempted solution:

$f(z)$ can be written as $\int_{0}^{1}f(z) dt$ so

$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int_{0}^{1}f(z+t\Delta z) dt = f(z) \iff $$

$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \bigg[ \int_{0}^{1}f(z+t\Delta z) dt - f(z) \bigg] = \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int_{0}^{1} [f(z+t\Delta z) - f(z) ]dt = 0 .$$

Let $$M = \max_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert f(z+t\Delta z) - f(z) \rvert .$$

$$0 \leq \bigg| \int_{0}^{1}f(z+t\Delta z) - f(z) dt \bigg| \leq \int_{0}^{1} \lvert f(z+t\Delta z) - f(z) \rvert dt \leq M .$$

Now I think I need to show that taking $\Delta z \to 0$ implies $M \to 0$ but I don't know how. I think I have to employ the continuity of $f$, since I haven't used that yet.

If anyone could help me finish this proof, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: This problem look suspicious: in Saff&Snider's text, the problem comes from a proof just before the exercises' section, where $\;f\;$ is given continuous **in a domain** $\;D\;$ . Here, we only have continuity at point $\;t=z\;$ ...In fact, with only this assumption, I am not sure whether $\;M\;$ exists at all, though perhaps the very assumption the given integral exists can gives us boundness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|h|<\delta$, $|f(z+h) - f(z) |<\varepsilon$. In particular, if $|\Delta z|<\delta$, you may replace $M$ above with $\varepsilon$, and so you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need some extra clarification though. If I understand correctly, if we can show $M \to 0$ as $\Delta z \to 0$ then the squeeze theorem will make $|f(z+t \Delta z) - f(z)| \to 0$. But I'm having trouble justifying the step $lim_{\Delta z \to 0} [max_{t \in [0,1]} |f(z+t \Delta z) - f(z)|] = 0$. Do you have any suggestions about this? I know the absolute value function is continuous, but can we interchange the limit and max?

Comment: This isn't really a squeeze theorem problem, it's just using the definition of limits. Use $\varepsilon $-$\delta$ arguments, as I have done above, to prove your desired limit (remember, if $|\Delta z|<\delta$, then $|t\Delta z|<\delta$ for all $t\in[0,1]$!)